# create epub formatted for iPhone

Tags: iphone, epub

I'd like to create an ePub book formatted to the iPhone's screen specs. Can you point me to resources??

Note that CALIBRE doesn't have iPhone resolution presets and does a straight convert. I'd like to be able to mark up and work out formatting issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/). It allows you to convert to ePub from a wide range of formats.

See the full list of supported formats [here](http://calibre-ebook.com/user_manual/faq.html#what-formats-does-app-support-conversion-to-from).

Comment: Tried it, but I'd like finer control over what appears on the screen tailored to the iPhone screen. That is, using some sort of template or spec that makes it as though it were written for iPHone, not just converted with the pages too big.

Answer (score 1):

EPub files shouldn't need re-formatting for anything. The whole aim of the standard is that the content is "reflowable" meaning that it can be re-formatted to suit the device displaying it.

In short, content (supplied by the ePub) is separated from the format (determined by the reader on the device).

If you want better control over what is displayed (you have something that needs specific formatting, such as a technical manual), convert to a less flexible format, like PDF.

Comment: So the only way to really know if it's going to work is to create a doc and test it by converting? No fine-grained control?

Comment: I have to admit, I've never created an ePub document (beyond automated conversions), so I don't know if there are any hacks you can do. Although they would defeat the purpose of the standard, they may well exist - for instance, HTML and CSS were supposed to decouple content and presentation, but in practice that strict ideal is very rarely achieved.

What issue in particular do you have with ePub on the iPhone? Have you tried using a different reader? I'd recommend Stanza - it gives a lot more control over presentation than iBooks.

Answer (score 0):

if you are working on a Mac, Apple's own software Pages which is part of the iLife suite can export to ePub now.